# How to display progress bar in dailog box before video loads

Tags: android, dialog, progress-bar, android-videoview

My app plays a video in dailog box on button click. I want a progress bar to be displayed before video plays in the dailog box. But when the button is clicked the progress bar is not visible in the dailog box but the video plays.

My on button click method

```
public void plyvido(){
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.videodialog);
    dialog.show();
    MediaController mediacontroller = new MediaController(
        MainActivity.this);
    WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    lp.copyFrom(dialog.getWindow().getAttributes());

    dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);

    videoview = (VideoView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.videodialogVideoView);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) dialog.findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
    mediacontroller.setAnchorView(videoview);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(VideoURL);
    videoview.setZOrderOnTop(true);
    videoview.setVideoURI(uri);
    videoview.setMediaController(mediacontroller);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    videoview.start();



    //progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    videoview.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                mp.start();
                mp.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnVideoSizeChangedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onVideoSizeChanged(MediaPlayer mp, int arg1,
                                                       int arg2) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            mp.start();
                        }
                    });

            }
        });


}
```